# UnboundLocalError (local variable referenced before assignment)

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm trying to make this part where the script searches a Tracking Number and prints the content of the .txt document. There is this error when I use this part:

```
def lookup_trackingnum():
    logger.info('lookup_trackingnum started - B3                    ')
    print(' ')
    print(' ')
    print(' = = Look Up a Tracking Number = =  ')
    print(' ')
    print(' ')
    lookup_in = input('Tracking Number: ')
    try:
        lookup_path = 'lms19-files/exports/' + lookup_in + '.txt'
        logger.debug('lookup_path created - B3   -   BUG RESOLVING      ')
        with open(lookup_path, 'r') as lookup:
            logger.debug('lookup_path opened - B3   -   BUG RESOLVING       ')
            print(lookup.read())
            logger.debug('lookup_path printed - B3   -   BUG RESOLVING      ')
    except:
        print('ERROR: The Tracking Number ' + lookup_in + ' doesn\'t exist.')
        logger.error('Tracking Number doesn\'t exist - B2                ')
        print(' ')
        print(' ')
        print(' [E] Return to Dashboard  ')
        print(' ')
        logger.debug('Before lookupnav_in input - B3   -   BUG RESOLVING')
        lookupnav_in = input('Input: ')
        logger.debug('After lookupnav_in input - B3   -   BUG RESOLVING ')
    if lookupnav_in == 'E':
        logger.debug('If lookupnav_in - B3   -   BUG RESOLVING          ')
        startmenu()
        logger.debug('startmenu triggered - B3   -   BUG RESOLVING      ')
    else:
        print(lookupnav_in + ' isn\'t a valid input.')
        logger.error('Invalid Input - B3                                ')
        startmenu()
```

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/lms19/lms19-beta.py", line 417, in <module>
    startmenu()
  File "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/lms19/lms19-beta.py", line 280, in startmenu
    lookup_trackingnum()
  File "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/lms19/lms19-beta.py", line 253, in lookup_trackingnum
    if lookupnav_in == 'E':
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lookupnav_in' referenced before assignment
```

**and the Log data:**

```
lms19 : INFO - Logger Started - B6                                 [2019/04/11 15:20:11]
lms19 : CRITICAL - Setup skipped - B6                              [2019/04/11 15:20:11]
lms19 : INFO - Software Initialised - B6                           [2019/04/11 15:20:11]
lms19 : INFO - Main Script started - B7                            [2019/04/11 15:20:11]
lms19 : INFO - startmenu started - B4                              [2019/04/11 15:20:11]
lms19 : INFO - lookup_trackingnum started - B3                     [2019/04/11 15:20:13]
lms19 : DEBUG - lookup_path created - B3   -   BUG RESOLVING       [2019/04/11 15:20:15]
lms19 : DEBUG - lookup_path opened - B3   -   BUG RESOLVING        [2019/04/11 15:20:15]
lms19 : DEBUG - lookup_path printed - B3   -   BUG RESOLVING       [2019/04/11 15:20:15]
```

I tried multiple things I found online (and on StackExchange) but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: What value do you expect `lookupnav_in` to have if your `try` block doesn't catch any exceptions? You need to initialize the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lookupnav_in = input('Input: ')
```

This is where you are defining the variable. It's in the except block of a try-statement.

```
if lookupnav_in == 'E':
```

This is where you are first using the variable. This is just outside the except block.

The except block is not executed unless the Exception actually occurs.

So think what would happen if the `try` never throws an exception.

The variable is never defined. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your variable *lookupnav_in* is declared in your Except block, and then checked with the if-statement *outside of your Except-block*. In the case where your Except-block isn't triggered, the variable never gets declared. That means you'd have to declare it somewhere else outside of that specific Except-block before it gets checked with the if-statement.